# How can I use an $_POST as an argument in php function

Tags: php, post

Okay, so I've been trying to create a PHP function with a `$_POST` as an argument. I've read a lot of posts that concerns $_POST as a global variable but I can't still seem to get it. I've been trying to get this code to work with lot of variations but I just can't seem to find the right formula.

Here's my code:

```
if($_POST['fname']){
$testing = $_POST['fname']
} 
function myTest($test)
{
    if($test)
    {
    $id=14; 
    $sql = "UPDATE stud_bas set fname=:fname WHERE stud_id=:id";
    $query = $db ->prepare($sql);
    $query -> bindValue  (':fname', $test);
    $query -> bindValue (':id', $id);
    $update = $query -> execute();
    }
}
```

myTest($testing);

So basically, I'm trying to create a function where different `$_POST` can use the same function. The current function it still in being modified.

But the bottom line is I can't make the `$_POST` work for the function...
I'm sorry, I didn't notice I didn't include how I call the function. 
I just used

`myTest($testing);`

Amother variation is I insert `myTest($testing);` inside the `if($_POST)`

Comment: $_POST is globally accessible. So you don't have to pass to your function. Try once with $_REQUEST

Comment: How do you call the function?  What doesn't work?

Comment: As said kakkar, don't use parametr for your function, define variable with post inside your function

Comment: the $_XXX variables are superglobals. they're automatically available/visible in all scopes.

Comment: `$db` is not available in the function.

Comment: In order for `$db` and `$id` to be available in the function, you need to add `global $db; global $id;` to the top of `myTest()`.

Comment: That is not necessarily true @MarcB, since a user can define variables starting with underscore

Comment: well, the ones built by PHP automatically are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $_POST is a superglobal. you don't need to pass the entire $_POST array around. If you want to use a function to process parts of $_POST, you can just pass the relevant array index, e.g.

```
$_POST['foo'] = 'bar';

function somefunc($arg) {
    echo $_POST[$arg];
}

somefunc('foo'); // outputs 'bar'
```

Comment: beat me about a few seconds

Comment: Thank you! I've been rattling my mind on this problem and this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** recommend filtering your input, before inserting it into your Database to prohibit XSS and SQL Injections.

For example:

```
$filteredPostFoo = filter_input ( INPUT_POST, "bar", FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS );
```